# copyTo Google Sheets Script for Send data workbook

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am very new to Javascript and Apps Script. I want to create a function that updates another sheet based on a date in a certain range of the active sheet. I run and no error but it doesn't transfer value from active sheet to sheet named "Master", in different target url google sheet

[data master post](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jQ93ylP0MHzSzxH0myS9_AhTjetdvLQMXvFwg18XFEE/edit#gid=0)

[output 1](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ShPxDW9qhz4aWgaQ1G9oz7w1yh0-Wfe2VItet95UYks/edit?usp=sharing)

[output 2](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13Dx3ZOpV7baSTadSApIrVVccN-bHrPlHu240Aux0fo0/edit?usp=sharing)

[output 3](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14EVlqaP1ilXwopgi0ESvp_IKkSyROSF22WzWAcNAJWc/edit?usp=sharing)

```
function updateYTD4() {
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("January");
const targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Master");
if (sheet && targetSheet) {
if(sheet.getRange("A2:D32").getValues().length > 0){
  sheet.getRange("A2:D32").copyTo(targetSheet.getRange("C"+(targetSheet.getLastRow()+1)), 
{contentsOnly:true});
}
}
}
```

copyTo Google Sheets Script for different workbook how targetSheet change to send data sheet to output 1 , output 2, output 3 ( with a different workbook url )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As another approach, how about the following sample script?
I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to use both the source Spreadsheet and the target Spreadsheet.
- The source Spreadsheet is the active Spreadsheet, and the target Spreadsheet is a different Spreadsheet from the source Spreadsheet.

#### Modification points:

- In the current stage, when the source Spreadsheet is different from the target Spreadsheet, `copyTo` of Class Range cannot be used. When this is used an error like `Exception: Target range and source range must be on the same spreadsheet.` occurs. Please be careful about this.
- In the case of `sheet.getRange("A2:D32").getValues().length > 0`, even when "A2:D32" are empty, the length is always 31. Please be careful about this.

In your situation, it seems that you want to copy only the values. So, how about using `getValues` and `setValues`? When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

##### Modified script:

```js
function myFunction1() {
  const srcSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const dstSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("###"); // Please set your spreadsheet ID.

  const srcSheet = srcSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("January");
  const targetSheet = dstSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("Master");

  if (srcSheet && targetSheet) {
    const values = srcSheet.getRange("A2:D32").getValues();
    if (values.filter(r => r.join("")).length > 0) {
      targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 3, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
    }
  }
}
```

If you have multiple Spreadsheet IDs, how about the following sample script?

```js
function myFunction2() {
  const spreadsheetIds = ["###", "###", "###"];// Please set your spreadshet IDs.

  const srcSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const srcSheet = srcSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("January");
  if (!srcSheet) return;
  const values = srcSheet.getRange("A2:D32").getValues();
  if (values.filter(r => r.join("")).length == 0) return;
  for (let i = 0; i < spreadsheetIds.length; i++) {
    const dstSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetIds[i]);
    const targetSheet = dstSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("Master");
    if (targetSheet) {
      targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 3, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
    }
  }
}
```

#### References:

- [copyTo(destination, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range?hl=ja#copytodestination,-options)
- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range?hl=ja#getvalues)
- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range?hl=ja#setvaluesvalues)

Comment: Tanaike, thanks again for knowledge given

Comment: Tanaike sorry ask ?
const targetSheet = dstSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("Master");, how change SheetByName cab1, cab2, cab3.   for 3 const spreadsheetIds = ["###", "###", "###"]

Comment: @dra Is your new question [https://stackoverflow.com/q/75255637](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75255637)? If my understanding is correct, I answered it. Please confirm it.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're handling different workbooks.

`const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();` will only refer to the workbook from which you run the script.

You should add a new variable for the other sheet:

```
const newss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1jQ93ylP0MHzSzxH0myS9_AhTjetdvLQMXvFwg18XFEE")
```

I've put the ID from the link from the mastersheet, but adapt accordingly to your needs. Then you can use `newss.getSheetByName("Sheet you need")`

### UPDATE

Possible code, if I understand you well:

```
function updateYTD4() {
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const newss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1jQ93ylP0MHzSzxH0myS9_AhTjetdvLQMXvFwg18XFEE")
const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("January");
const targetSheet = newss.getSheetByName("Master");
if (sheet && targetSheet) {
if(sheet.getRange("A2:D32").getValues().length > 0){
  sheet.getRange("A2:D32").copyTo(targetSheet.getRange("C"+(targetSheet.getLastRow()+1)), 
{contentsOnly:true});
}
}
}
```

Comment: thanks Martin. May I ask for the complete script code? or change in sheet code for sample. Martin